# Why two datatriggers isn't work, just last one?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How right fix my error with two `DataTrigger`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="250"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" >
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="250"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="companyStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" >        
        <Style.Triggers>               

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBoxRole}" Value="AppDeveloper">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBoxRole}" Value="EndUser">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}"/>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>                

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>        

</Page.Resources>
```

Here I call same property for the different situation (call `open` if value -**developer**, call `close` if value - **user** ). When I choose the value in the `combobox`, I want to show or hide the developer fields.

And a better version if when opacity will 0, change the property `visability= collapse`.

Sorry, maybe a bit stupid question but can't find how to write this logic right. And True or false doesn't help me, because I can add some more Combobox items and fields

My combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxRole" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Role}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RolesEnum}" 
                  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Choose the role" 
                  Foreground="RoyalBlue"
                  FontWeight="Heavy"
                  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="0,90,0,0"
                  Width="150"                      
                  />
```

and for example some developer's fields

```
<!-- Company adress -->
                <TextBox x:Name="companyAdress" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Company adress" Style="{StaticResource companyStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,20" FontSize="18" Foreground="RoyalBlue" FontWeight="Heavy">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding  Mode="TwoWay" Path="CompanyAdress"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False"/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>

                <!-- Company website -->
                <TextBox x:Name="companyWebsite" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Company Website" Style="{StaticResource companyStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,20" FontSize="18" Foreground="RoyalBlue" FontWeight="Heavy">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding  Mode="TwoWay" Path="CompanyWebsite"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False"/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Storyboards` are defined exactly the same. Anyway, you could use an `ExitAction` to remove the `Storyboard`. This example works:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OpenMenu">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" >
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="CloseMenu">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" >
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="companyStyle" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBoxRole}" Value="AppDeveloper">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="sb" Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenMenu}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=comboBoxRole}" Value="EndUser">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="sb2" Storyboard="{StaticResource CloseMenu}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb2" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource companyStyle}" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxRole" SelectedValuePath="Content">
            <ComboBoxItem>AppDeveloper</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>EndUser</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: it's my mistake, in a project I did it different and it doesn't work the same problem. sorry, edit a bit

Comment: I wrote about my example and my the same  `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`. Your work great!!!!!! thank you!. Can you tell me how I can add the property Visibility = collapse/visible? I wrote it in a question. or it's other question?

Comment: "A question"? Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Thank you) I Understand all what you mean.